# Making a Simple Deb Package NixOS Compatible (Mathematica's wolframscript)

Tags: deb, nixos

Consider this simple debian package: [wolframscript.deb](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/) (to inspect you'll have to click the download link for Linux). After unpacking, it has the following file structure:

```
├── opt
│   └── Wolfram
│       └── WolframScript
│           └── bin
│               └── wolframscript
└── usr
    ├── local
    │   └── share
    │       └── man
    │           └── man1
    │               └── wolframscript.1
    └── share
        ├── icons
        │   └── hicolor
        │       ├── 128x128
        │       │   └── mimetypes
        │       │       └── application-vnd.wolfram.wls.png
        │       ├── 32x32
        │       │   └── mimetypes
        │       │       └── application-vnd.wolfram.wls.png
        │       └── 64x64
        │           └── mimetypes
        │               └── application-vnd.wolfram.wls.png
        └── mime
            └── packages
                └── application-vnd.wolfram.wls.xml
```

The only relevant file is the `opt/Wolfram/WolframScript/bin/wolframscript` binary (I think). I tried executing this plainly but I get a `bash: ./wolframscript: No such file or directory` error. How do I make this binary/package usable in NixOS?

**EDIT:** To answer @muru's question:

```bsh
$ file opt/Wolfram/WolframScript/bin/wolframscript
opt/Wolfram/WolframScript/bin/wolframscript: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib
```

```bsh
$ ldd opt/Wolfram/WolframScript/bin/wolframscript
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff767c9000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /nix/store/7gx4kiv5m0i7d7qkixq2cwzbr10lvxwc-glibc-2.27/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f55b8525000)
        librt.so.1 => /nix/store/7gx4kiv5m0i7d7qkixq2cwzbr10lvxwc-glibc-2.27/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f55b831d000)
        libdl.so.2 => /nix/store/7gx4kiv5m0i7d7qkixq2cwzbr10lvxwc-glibc-2.27/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f55b8119000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => not found
        libm.so.6 => /nix/store/7gx4kiv5m0i7d7qkixq2cwzbr10lvxwc-glibc-2.27/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f55b7d84000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /nix/store/7gx4kiv5m0i7d7qkixq2cwzbr10lvxwc-glibc-2.27/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f55b7b6e000)
        libc.so.6 => /nix/store/7gx4kiv5m0i7d7qkixq2cwzbr10lvxwc-glibc-2.27/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f55b77ba000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /nix/store/7gx4kiv5m0i7d7qkixq2cwzbr10lvxwc-glibc-2.27/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f55b874400
```

Comment: What do `file opt/Wolfram/WolframScript/bin/wolframscript` and `ldd opt/Wolfram/WolframScript/bin/wolframscript` report?

Comment: @muru I added this to my question.

Comment: So your no-such-file error is due to the missing `libstdc++` library. Install that and the file should be good to go.

Comment: @muru: Since I run NixOS this is not so straightforward.

Comment: Dunno about NixOS, but libstdc++ is a very commonly used library - most C++ programs would need it. Maybe https://nixos.org/nix-dev/2016-August/021431.html would be of help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presented [here a full list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522822/different-methods-to-run-a-non-nixos-executable-on-nixos/522823#522823) of methods to solve your problem, with example files. The two more efficient methods are `autoPatchelfHook` (prefered, as Vladimír Čunát was suggesting), or eventually `steam-run` (based on `buildFHSUserEnv` with lot's of default libraries) when you mostly want a quick-and-dirty-fix.

Here is a quick summary:

## Proper method with `autoPatchelfHook`

NixOs did for us a special "hook" `autoPatchelfHook` that automatically patches everything for you! You just need to specify it in `(native)BuildInputs`, and nix does the magic. Put in `derivation.nix`:

```
{ stdenv, dpkg, glibc, gcc-unwrapped, autoPatchelfHook }:
let

  # Please keep the version x.y.0.z and do not update to x.y.76.z because the
  # source of the latter disappears much faster.
  version = "12.0.0";

  src = ./WolframScript_12.0.0_LINUX64_amd64.deb;

in stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "wolframscript-${version}";

  system = "x86_64-linux";

  inherit src;

  # Required for compilation
  nativeBuildInputs = [
    autoPatchelfHook # Automatically setup the loader, and do the magic
    dpkg
  ];

  # Required at running time
  buildInputs = [
    glibc
    gcc-unwrapped
  ];

  unpackPhase = "true";

  # Extract and copy executable in $out/bin
  installPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $out
    dpkg -x $src $out
    cp -av $out/opt/Wolfram/WolframScript/* $out
    rm -rf $out/opt
  '';

  meta = with stdenv.lib; {
    description = "Wolframscript";
    homepage = https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/;
    license = licenses.mit;
    maintainers = with stdenv.lib.maintainers; [ ];
    platforms = [ "x86_64-linux" ];
  };
}
```

and in `default.nix`:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

pkgs.callPackage ./derivation.nix {}
```

compile and run with

```
nix-build
result/bin/wolframscript
```

## Quicker method, with `steam-run`

Nix provides `buildFHSUserEnv` that fakes a classic linux. You can use it directly and add the libraries to it, or if you prefer `steam-run` contains already lot's of libraries (despite the name it's independent of steam). Note that this method is heavier and requires a longer startup, so avoid it when it's possible.

You just need to install `steam-run` (you need to allow unfree softwares, with `{ allowUnfree = true; }` in `~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix` or if you use `nixos-rebuild`, use in your `configuration.nix` the line `nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true;`), and then run:

```
steam-run ./wolframscript
```

Fore more details, see [Different methods to run a non-nixos executable on Nixos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522822/different-methods-to-run-a-non-nixos-executable-on-nixos/522823#522823)

Comment: I don't know. I +1'ed it and am reading it now.

Answer (score 1):

I expect it will be best to create a simple nix expression that has this deb as input, unpacks it etc.  so you have this installed "in nix way" (e.g. dependencies won't be deleted before the path itself).  When you do that, adding `autoPatchelfHook` into `buildInputs` should fix these missing references.