# Different methods to run a non-nixos executable on Nixos

Tags: executable, nixos

What are the different methods to run a non-nixos executable on NixOs? (For instance proprietary binaries.) I'd like to see also the manual methods.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

**Related answers**

If you plan to package a binary and not just run it, you might like this other answer of mine: [How to package my software in nix or write my own package derivation for nixpkgs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/717168/how-to-package-my-software-in-nix-or-write-my-own-package-derivation-for-nixpkgs/717169?noredirect=1#comment1464428_717169)

**Short version**

Quick and dirty: make sure `steam-run` is installed (strange name, it has nothing to do with steam), e.g. `nix-shell -p steam-run`, then:

```
$ steam-run ./your-binary
```

Since the creation of this answer, other alternatives to steam-run have been developed, see e.g. `nix-ld` that is now part of NixOs (that basically recreates the missing loaders in `/lib`… I **hightly** recommend you to configure it once for all, this way you won't need anymore to bother about running non-patched binaries, so you can use NPM etc without headaches):

(**warning**: since recent nix update, you only need `programs.nix-ld.enable = true;`, and variables can be configured using

```
programs.nix-ld.enable = true;
## If needed, you can add missing libraries here. nix-index-database is your friend to
## find the name of the package from the error message:
## https://github.com/nix-community/nix-index-database
programs.nix-ld.libraries = options.programs.nix-ld.libraries.default ++ (with pkgs; [ yourlibrary ]);
```

to automatically set the environment variables, but the code below should work also on legacy systems, so I'll let it here) Note that you might also need to reboot to make sure the environment variables are set correctly, not tested recently.

```
  programs.nix-ld.enable = true;
  environment.variables = {
      NIX_LD_LIBRARY_PATH = with pkgs; lib.makeLibraryPath [
        stdenv.cc.cc
        openssl
        xorg.libXcomposite
        xorg.libXtst
        xorg.libXrandr
        xorg.libXext
        xorg.libX11
        xorg.libXfixes
        libGL
        libva
        pipewire.lib
        xorg.libxcb
        xorg.libXdamage
        xorg.libxshmfence
        xorg.libXxf86vm
        libelf
        
        # Required
        glib
        gtk2
        bzip2
        
        # Without these it silently fails
        xorg.libXinerama
        xorg.libXcursor
        xorg.libXrender
        xorg.libXScrnSaver
        xorg.libXi
        xorg.libSM
        xorg.libICE
        gnome2.GConf
        nspr
        nss
        cups
        libcap
        SDL2
        libusb1
        dbus-glib
        ffmpeg
        # Only libraries are needed from those two
        libudev0-shim
        
        # Verified games requirements
        xorg.libXt
        xorg.libXmu
        libogg
        libvorbis
        SDL
        SDL2_image
        glew110
        libidn
        tbb
        
        # Other things from runtime
        flac
        freeglut
        libjpeg
        libpng
        libpng12
        libsamplerate
        libmikmod
        libtheora
        libtiff
        pixman
        speex
        SDL_image
        SDL_ttf
        SDL_mixer
        SDL2_ttf
        SDL2_mixer
        libappindicator-gtk2
        libdbusmenu-gtk2
        libindicator-gtk2
        libcaca
        libcanberra
        libgcrypt
        libvpx
        librsvg
        xorg.libXft
        libvdpau
        gnome2.pango
        cairo
        atk
        gdk-pixbuf
        fontconfig
        freetype
        dbus
        alsaLib
        expat
        # Needed for electron
        libdrm
        mesa
        libxkbcommon
      ];
      NIX_LD = lib.fileContents "${pkgs.stdenv.cc}/nix-support/dynamic-linker";
  };
```

There is also [nix-alien](https://github.com/thiagokokada/nix-alien) / [nix-autobahn](https://github.com/Lassulus/nix-autobahn) that also automatically try to add the missing libraries. Finally you can use [distrobox](https://github.com/89luca89/distrobox) that provides you any distribution in a docker/podman container tightly integrated with the host… but from my experience it is more complicated to use that `nix-ld` that is truly transparent.

Here is a longer and more detailed explanation, together with various methods, often less dirty.

**Long version**

Here are several methods (the manual ones are mostly for educational purpose as most of the time writing a proper derivation is better). I'm not an expert at all, and I did this list also to learn nix, so if you have better methods, let me know!

So the main issue is that the executable call first a loader, and then needs some libraries to work, and nixos put both the loader and the libraries in `/nix/store/`.

This list gives all the methods I found so far. There are basically three "groups":

- the full manual: interesting for educational purpose, and to understand what's going on, but that's all (don't use them in practice because nothing will prevent the derivations used to be garbage collected later)
- the patched versions: these methods try to modify the executable (automatically when using the recommended method 4 with autoPatchelfHook) to make the point to the good library directly
- the methods based on FHS, that basically fake a "normal linux" (more heavy to run than the patched version, so this should be avoided if possible).

I would recommend method 4 with `autoPatchelfHook` for a real, proper setup, and if you don't have time and just want to run a binary in one-line, you may be interested by the quick-and-dirty solution based on `steam-run` (method 7).

## Method 1) Dirty manual method, no patch

You need to first find the loader with for example `file`:

```
$ file wolframscript
wolframscript: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=079684175aa38e3633b60544681b338c0e8831e0, stripped
```

Here the loader is `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. To find the loader of nixos, you can do:

```
$ ls /nix/store/*glibc*/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

You also need to find to find the libraries that your program require, for example with `ldd` or `LD_DEBUG=libs`:

```
$ ldd wolframscript
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe8fff9000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /nix/store/sw54ph775lw7b9g4hlfvpx6fmlvdy8qi-glibc-2.27/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f86aa321000)
        librt.so.1 => /nix/store/sw54ph775lw7b9g4hlfvpx6fmlvdy8qi-glibc-2.27/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f86aa317000)
        libdl.so.2 => /nix/store/sw54ph775lw7b9g4hlfvpx6fmlvdy8qi-glibc-2.27/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f86aa312000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => not found
        libm.so.6 => /nix/store/sw54ph775lw7b9g4hlfvpx6fmlvdy8qi-glibc-2.27/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f86aa17c000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /nix/store/sw54ph775lw7b9g4hlfvpx6fmlvdy8qi-glibc-2.27/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f86a9f66000)
        libc.so.6 => /nix/store/sw54ph775lw7b9g4hlfvpx6fmlvdy8qi-glibc-2.27/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f86a9dae000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /nix/store/sw54ph775lw7b9g4hlfvpx6fmlvdy8qi-glibc-2.27/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f86aa344000)
```

Here, you see that most libraries are found except `libstdc++.so.6`. So let's find them! A first quick and dirty way to find them is to check if they are already present in your system:

```
$ find /nix/store -name libstdc++.so.6
/nix/store/12zhmzzhrwszdc8q3fwgifpwjkwi3mzc-gcc-7.3.0-lib/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

In case the library is not already installed, you will certainly prefer to use the more involved [`nix-index`](https://github.com/bennofs/nix-index) program to search for these files in a much larger database (thanks hydra). For that, first install `nix-index` and generate the database (this is only needed the first time, but it can take a few minutes to run):

```
$ nix-index
```

(you can also use `nix run github:mic92/nix-index-database yourlib` to avoid recreating the database locally. See also `nix-index-update` from [nix-alien](https://github.com/thiagokokada/nix-alien) to download the cache automatically from [nix-index-database](https://github.com/Mic92/nix-index-database)) then, to search for a library you can do something like (note that `--top-level` removes some entries):

```
$ nix-locate lib/libstdc++.so.6 --top-level
…
gcc-unwrapped.lib                                     0 s /nix/store/7fv9v6mnlkb4ddf9kz1snknbvbfbcbx0-gcc-10.3.0-lib/lib/libstdc++.so.6
…
```

Then you can install these libraries for this quick and dirty example (later we will see better solutions).

Good. Now, we just need to run the program with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` configured to point to this file (see also `makeLibraryPath` to generate this string in a derivation), and call the loader we determined at the first step on this file:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/nix/store/12zhmzzhrwszdc8q3fwgifpwjkwi3mzc-gcc-7.3.0-lib/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./wolframscript
```

(make sure to use `./` before the script name, and to keep only the directory of the libraries. If you have several libraries, just use concat the path with colons)

## Method 2) Dirty manual method, with patch

After installing (with `nixenv -i` or in your `configuration.nix`) `patchelf`, you can also directly modify the executable to pack the good loader and libraries. To change the loader just run:

```
patchelf --set-interpreter /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 wolframscript
```

and to check:

```
$ patchelf --print-interpreter wolframscript
/nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.
```

and to change the path to the libraries hardcoded in the executable, first check what is the current rpath (empty for me):

```
$ patchelf --print-rpath wolframscript
```

and append them to the library path you determined before, eventually separated with colons:

```
$ patchelf --set-rpath /nix/store/12zhmzzhrwszdc8q3fwgifpwjkwi3mzc-gcc-7.3.0-lib/lib/ wolframscript
$ ./wolframscript
```

## Method 3) Patch in a nix derivation

We can reproduce more or less the same thing in a nix derivation inspired by [skypeforlinux](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/applications/networking/instant-messengers/skypeforlinux/default.nix)

This example presents also an alternative, either you can use:

```
patchelf --set-interpreter ${glibc}/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 "$out/bin/wolframscript" || true
```

(which should be pretty clear once you understand the "manual" method), or

```
patchelf --set-interpreter "$(cat $NIX_CC/nix-support/dynamic-linker)" "$out/bin/wolframscript" || true
```

This second method is a bit more subtle, but if you run:

```
$ nix-shell '<nixpkgs>' -A hello --run 'echo $NIX_CC/nix-support/dynamic-linker "->" $(cat $NIX_CC/nix-support/dynamic-linker)'
/nix/store/8zfm4i1aw4c3l5n6ay311ds6l8vd9983-gcc-wrapper-7.4.0/nix-support/dynamic-linker -> /nix/store/sw54ph775lw7b9g4hlfvpx6fmlvdy8qi-glibc-2.27/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

you will see that the file `$NIX_CC/nix-support/dynamic-linker` contains a path to the loader `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.

Put in `derivation.nix`, this is

```
{ stdenv, dpkg,glibc, gcc-unwrapped }:
let

  # Please keep the version x.y.0.z and do not update to x.y.76.z because the
  # source of the latter disappears much faster.
  version = "12.0.0";

  rpath = stdenv.lib.makeLibraryPath [
    gcc-unwrapped
    glibc
  ];
  # What is it for?
  # + ":${stdenv.cc.cc.lib}/lib64";

  src = ./WolframScript_12.0.0_LINUX64_amd64.deb;

in stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "wolframscript-${version}";

  system = "x86_64-linux";

  inherit src;

  nativeBuildInputs = [
  ];

  buildInputs = [ dpkg ];

  unpackPhase = "true";

  # Extract and copy executable in $out/bin
  installPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $out
    dpkg -x $src $out
    cp -av $out/opt/Wolfram/WolframScript/* $out
    rm -rf $out/opt
  '';

  postFixup = ''
    # Why does the following works?
    patchelf --set-interpreter "$(cat $NIX_CC/nix-support/dynamic-linker)" "$out/bin/wolframscript" || true
    # or
    # patchelf --set-interpreter ${glibc}/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 "$out/bin/wolframscript" || true
    patchelf --set-rpath ${rpath} "$out/bin/wolframscript" || true
  '';

  meta = with stdenv.lib; {
    description = "Wolframscript";
    homepage = https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/;
    license = licenses.unfree;
    maintainers = with stdenv.lib.maintainers; [ ];
    platforms = [ "x86_64-linux" ];
  };
}
```

and in `default.nix` put:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

pkgs.callPackage ./derivation.nix {}
```

Compile and run with

```
nix-build
result/bin/wolframscript
```

## Method 4) Use autoPatchElf: simpler

All the previous methods need a bit of work (you need to find the executables, patch them...). NixOs did for us a special "hook" `autoPatchelfHook` that automatically patches everything for you! You just need to specify it in `(native)BuildInputs`, and nix does the magic.

```
{ stdenv, dpkg, glibc, gcc-unwrapped, autoPatchelfHook }:
let

  # Please keep the version x.y.0.z and do not update to x.y.76.z because the
  # source of the latter disappears much faster.
  version = "12.0.0";

  src = ./WolframScript_12.0.0_LINUX64_amd64.deb;

in stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "wolframscript-${version}";

  system = "x86_64-linux";

  inherit src;

  # Required for compilation
  nativeBuildInputs = [
    autoPatchelfHook # Automatically setup the loader, and do the magic
    dpkg
  ];

  # Required at running time
  buildInputs = [
    glibc
    gcc-unwrapped
  ];

  unpackPhase = "true";

  # Extract and copy executable in $out/bin
  installPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $out
    dpkg -x $src $out
    cp -av $out/opt/Wolfram/WolframScript/* $out
    rm -rf $out/opt
  '';

  meta = with stdenv.lib; {
    description = "Wolframscript";
    homepage = https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/;
    license = licenses.mit;
    maintainers = with stdenv.lib.maintainers; [ ];
    platforms = [ "x86_64-linux" ];
  };
}
```

## Method 5) Use FHS to simulate a classic linux shell, and manually execute the files

Some sofware may be hard to package that way because they may heavily rely on the [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) file tree structure, or may check that the binary are unchanged. You can then also use [buildFHSUserEnv](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-fhs-environments) to provide an FHS file structure (lightweight, using namespaces) for your application. **Note that this method is heavier that the patch-based methods, and add significant startup time, so avoid it when possible**

You can either just spawn a shell and then manually extract the archive and execute the file, or directly package your program for the FHS. Let's first see how to get a shell. Put in a file (say `fhs-env.nix`) the following:

```
let nixpkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
in nixpkgs.buildFHSUserEnv {
   name = "fhs";
   targetPkgs = pkgs: [];
   multiPkgs = pkgs: [ pkgs.dpkg ];
   runScript = "bash";
}
```

and run:

```
nix-build fhs-env.nix
result/bin/fhs
```

You will then get a bash in a more standard-looking linux, and you can run commands to run your executable, like:

```
mkdir wolf_fhs/
dpkg -x WolframScript_12.0.0_LINUX64_amd64.deb wolf_fhs/
cd wolf_fhs/opt/Wolfram/WolframScript/bin/
./wolfram
```

If you need more libraries/programs as dependencies, just add them to `multiPkgs` (for all supported archs) or `targetPkgs` (for current arch only).

Bonus: you can also launch a fhs shell with a one line command, without creating a specifc file:

```
nix-build -E '(import <nixpkgs> {}).buildFHSUserEnv {name = "fhs";}' && ./result/bin/fhs
```

## Method 6) Use FHS to simulate a classic linux shell, and pack the files inside

source: https://reflexivereflection.com/posts/2015-02-28-deb-installation-nixos.html

## Method 7) steam-run

With `buildFHSUserEnv` you can run lot's of softwares, but you will need to specify manually all the required libraries. If you want a quick solution and you don't have time to check precisely what are the required libraries, you may want to try `steam-run` (despite the name, it is not linked directly with steam, and just packs lots of libraries), which is like `buildFHSUserEnv` with lot's of common libraries preinstalled (some of them may be non-free like `steamrt` that packs some nvidia code, thanks simpson!). To use it, just install `steam-run`, and then:

```
steam-run ./wolframscript
```

or if you want a full shell:

```
steam-run bash
```

Note that you may need to add `nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true;` (or whitelist [this specific package](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-allow-unfree)) if you want to install it with `nixos-rebuild`, and if you want to run/install it with `nix-shell`/`nix-env` you need to put `{ allowUnfree = true; }` in `~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix`.

It is not easy to "overwrite" packages or libraries to nix-shell, but if you want to make a wrapper around your script, you can either manually create a wrapper script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nix-shell
#!nix-shell -i bash -p steam-run
exec steam-run ./wolframscript "$@"
```

or directly write it in a nixos derivation :

```
{ stdenv, steam-run, writeScriptBin }:
let
  src = ./opt/Wolfram/WolframScript/bin/wolframscript;
in writeScriptBin "wolf_wrapped_steam" ''
    exec ${steam-run}/bin/steam-run ${src} "$@"
  ''
```

or if you start from the .deb (here I used `makeWrapper` instead):

```
{ stdenv, steam-run, dpkg, writeScriptBin, makeWrapper }:
stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "wolframscript";
  src = ./WolframScript_12.0.0_LINUX64_amd64.deb;

  nativeBuildInputs = [
    dpkg makeWrapper
  ];
  unpackPhase = "true";
  installPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $out/bin
    dpkg -x $src $out
    cp -av $out/opt/Wolfram/WolframScript/bin/wolframscript $out/bin/.wolframscript-unwrapped
    makeWrapper ${steam-run}/bin/steam-run $out/bin/wolframscript --add-flags $out/bin/.wolframscript-unwrapped
    rm -rf $out/opt
  '';
}
```

(if you are too tired to write the usual `default.nix`, you can run directly `nix-build -E "with import <nixpkgs> {}; callPackage ./derivation.nix {}"`)

## Method 8) Using `nix-ld`

If you do not want to spawn a sandbox as we did for steam-run (in sandboxes it's impossible to run setuid apps, sandboxes can't be nested, poor integration with the system packages included direnv), you can recreate the missing loader system-wide by putting in your `configuration.nix`:

```
  programs.nix-ld.enable = true;
```

You can see that the file is now present:

```
$ ls /lib64/
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

However it is still impossible to run binaries as the new `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` file only redirects to the loader in `NIX_LD` (this way multiple programs can use different loaders while being on the same system):

```
$ ./blender 
cannot execute ./blender: NIX_LD or NIX_LD_x86_64-linux is not set
```

To locally create this environment variable, you can do something like:

```
$ cat shell.nix 
with import <nixpkgs> {};
mkShell {
  NIX_LD_LIBRARY_PATH = lib.makeLibraryPath [
    stdenv.cc.cc
    openssl
    # ...
  ];
  NIX_LD = lib.fileContents "${stdenv.cc}/nix-support/dynamic-linker";
}

$ nix-shell 

[nix-shell:/tmp/blender-3.2.2-linux-x64]$ ./blender
```

or system-wide using:

(**warning**: since recent nix update, you only need `programs.nix-ld.enable = true;`, and variables can be configured using `programs.nix-ld.libraries = with pkgs; [];` instead of using environment variables, but the code below should work also on legacy systems, so I'll let it here)

```
  environment.variables = {
      NIX_LD_LIBRARY_PATH = lib.makeLibraryPath [
        pkgs.stdenv.cc.cc
        pkgs.openssl
        # ...
      ];
      NIX_LD = lib.fileContents "${pkgs.stdenv.cc}/nix-support/dynamic-linker";
  };
```

Note that you need to **restart** your X11 session everytime you change this file or do:

```
$ cat /etc/profile | grep set-environment
. /nix/store/clwf7wsykkjdhbd0v8vb94pvg81lnsba-set-environment
$ . /nix/store/clwf7wsykkjdhbd0v8vb94pvg81lnsba-set-environment
```

Note that (contrary to `steam-run`) `nix-ld` does not come with any library by default (actually, this is not true anymore, see the note on the top of this file to use the more modern interface with a default list… but the list is quite small) but you can add your own or use tools to do that automatically, see below. You can also get inspired by the list of libraries that steam-run packs here: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/games/steam/fhsenv.nix Here is for example the file I'm using for now, it is enough to run blender/electron:

```
  programs.nix-ld.enable = true;
  environment.variables = {
      NIX_LD_LIBRARY_PATH = with pkgs; lib.makeLibraryPath [
        stdenv.cc.cc
        openssl
        xorg.libXcomposite
        xorg.libXtst
        xorg.libXrandr
        xorg.libXext
        xorg.libX11
        xorg.libXfixes
        libGL
        libva
        pipewire.lib
        xorg.libxcb
        xorg.libXdamage
        xorg.libxshmfence
        xorg.libXxf86vm
        libelf
        
        # Required
        glib
        gtk2
        bzip2
        
        # Without these it silently fails
        xorg.libXinerama
        xorg.libXcursor
        xorg.libXrender
        xorg.libXScrnSaver
        xorg.libXi
        xorg.libSM
        xorg.libICE
        gnome2.GConf
        nspr
        nss
        cups
        libcap
        SDL2
        libusb1
        dbus-glib
        ffmpeg
        # Only libraries are needed from those two
        libudev0-shim
        
        # Verified games requirements
        xorg.libXt
        xorg.libXmu
        libogg
        libvorbis
        SDL
        SDL2_image
        glew110
        libidn
        tbb
        
        # Other things from runtime
        flac
        freeglut
        libjpeg
        libpng
        libpng12
        libsamplerate
        libmikmod
        libtheora
        libtiff
        pixman
        speex
        SDL_image
        SDL_ttf
        SDL_mixer
        SDL2_ttf
        SDL2_mixer
        libappindicator-gtk2
        libdbusmenu-gtk2
        libindicator-gtk2
        libcaca
        libcanberra
        libgcrypt
        libvpx
        librsvg
        xorg.libXft
        libvdpau
        gnome2.pango
        cairo
        atk
        gdk-pixbuf
        fontconfig
        freetype
        dbus
        alsaLib
        expat
        # Needed for electron
        libdrm
        mesa
        libxkbcommon
      ];
      NIX_LD = lib.fileContents "${pkgs.stdenv.cc}/nix-support/dynamic-linker";
  };
```

You can also find the name of the libraries, see above `nix-index`. You can also use [nix-alien-ld](https://github.com/thiagokokada/nix-alien) or [nix-autobahn](https://github.com/Lassulus/nix-autobahn) to automatically find and load the libraries for you. Note that if you don't have the right libraries you will get an error like

```
$ ./blender
./blender: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

You can see at once all the libraries that are not yet available using:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$NIX_LD_LIBRARY_PATH ldd turtl
        libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /nix/store/n9h110ffps25rdkkim5k802p3p5w476m-pango-1.50.6/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f02feb83000)
        libatk-1.0.so.0 => not found
…
```

## Method 9) nix-alien

[nix-alien](https://github.com/thiagokokada/nix-alien) automatically builds a FHS with the appropriates libraries. If you have flake enabled (otherwise just add replace `nix run` with `nix --extra-experimental-features "nix-command flakes" run`) you can simply run it this way (nix-alien is not yet packaged in 2022)

```
nix run github:thiagokokada/nix-alien -- yourprogram
```

It will then automatically find the library using nix-index, asking you some questions when it is not sure (this is cached).
[image]

Note that programs that rely on openGl need to use [nixGl](https://github.com/guibou/nixGL) to run (this certainly apply to other methods here):

```
nix run --impure github:guibou/nixGL --override-input nixpkgs nixpkgs/nixos-21.11 -- nix run github:thiagokokada/nix-alien -- blender
```

Note that you may need to change the version of `nixos-21.11` to ensure that the version of openGl matches your program.

Note that you can also see the automatically generated file (the path is given the first time the program is run):

```
$ cat /home/leo/.cache/nix-alien/87a5d119-f810-5222-9b47-4809257c60ec/fhs-env/default.nix
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> { } }:

let
  inherit (pkgs) buildFHSUserEnv;
in
buildFHSUserEnv {
  name = "blender-fhs";
  targetPkgs = p: with p; [
    xorg.libX11.out
    xorg.libXfixes.out
    xorg.libXi.out
    xorg.libXrender.out
    xorg.libXxf86vm.out
    xorg_sys_opengl.out
  ];
  runScript = "/tmp/blender-3.2.2-linux-x64/blender";
}
```

See also the other version working with nix-ld and [nix-autobahn](https://github.com/Lassulus/nix-autobahn).

## Method 9) Using containers/Docker (heavier)

TODO

Note that the project [distrobox](https://github.com/89luca89/distrobox) allows you to simply create new containers tightly integrated with the host installing any distribution you want.

## Method 10) Rely on flatpack/appimage

https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#module-services-flatpak

appimage-run : To test with, ex, musescore

## Sources or examples

- https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/5a9eaf02ae3c6403ce6f23d33ae569be3f9ce644/pkgs/applications/video/lightworks/default.nix
- https://sandervanderburg.blogspot.com/2015/10/deploying-prebuilt-binary-software-with.html
- https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/35c3396f41ec73c5e968a11f46d79a94db4042d7/pkgs/applications/networking/dropbox/default.nix

Also, for people wanting to get started in packaging, I wrote recently a similar tutorial [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/717168/how-to-write-my-own-package-derivation-for-nixpkgs/717169#717169).

Comment: To quote Mariah Carey, "[that was ... amazing](https://youtu.be/O4ResuAjG8k?t=176)".

Comment: tl;dr: `nix-shell -p steam-run --run "steam-run ./the-binary"`

Comment: @Busti Thanks, I was not expecting this answer to get much attention, I added your comment at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: NixOS is an amazing piece of software, but documentation is lacking, and sometimes if exist is scattered all over the place. This is NixOS Gem. Thanks a lot for all the effort on this answer. And I finally get to run some non-free applications thanks to this article.

Comment: Seems like `nix-ld` works without any extra configuration now, at least on unstable. All I did was enable it and now all pre-compiled binaries seem to work. The description of the default value of `programs.nix-ld.libraries` says `baseLibraries derived from systemd and nix dependencies.`