# How to get /bin/bash on nixos

Tags: nixos

So I know I can change she-bangs to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and I will do that for my scripts, but really I'd like to be able to just run the many many scripts with a `#!/bin/bash` she-bang. Sometimes it's easy to change, sometimes it isn't, because the script is run by some other thing, not you directly, and it's somewhere you don't really want to touch.

Is there some option I can enable in my system config to get a link at `/bin/bash`, also is there any reason I shouldn't want this, why isn't this the standard? (And please don't tell me something about a slippery slope, `/bin/bash` is probably one of the most common assumptions to make about a Unix system)

Comment: Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522823/117549 help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now the default shell on NixOS is Bash. Assuming you have not changed that then you can do the following in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`.

```
system.activationScripts.binbash = {
    deps = [ "binsh" ];
    text = ''
         ln -s /bin/sh /bin/bash
    '';
  };
```

Comment: Nice. I guess there should also be a way to get the path to bash in /nix. But this seems already nicer than just doing it manually.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure what the best way to do it would be, but I think the definition of binsh shows the way: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/8261f6e94510101738ab45f0b877f2993c7fb069/nixos/modules/config/shells-environment.nix#L137

Answer (score 5):

The standard POSIX shell is `sh`, not `bash`. So you can assume POSIX systems will have a bourne-compatible shell available and called `sh`, but there is no reason to assume they will have `bash` installed, nor that it will be at `/bin/bash`. In fact, [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html) doesn't even require `sh` to be `/bin/sh`:

> Applications should note that the standard PATH to the shell cannot be
> assumed to be either /bin/sh or /usr/bin/sh, and should be determined
> by interrogation of the PATH returned by getconf PATH , ensuring that
> the returned pathname is an absolute pathname and not a shell
> built-in.
>
> For example, to determine the location of the standard sh utility:
>
> ```
> command -v sh
> ```
>
> On some implementations this might return:
>
> ```
> /usr/xpg4/bin/sh
> ```
>
> Furthermore, on systems that support executable scripts (the "#!"
> construct), it is recommended that applications using executable
> scripts install them using getconf -v to determine the shell pathname
> and update the "#!" script appropriately as it is being installed (for
> example, with sed).

So the reason that `/bin/bash` isn't standard is that `bash` isn't standard. Which is precisely why `env` exists and why `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is [the portable solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/22222) for this sort of thing.

That said, if it's your system, that's completely up to you. There is no reason not to add a symlink in `/bin/bash` pointing to wherever your `bash` is installed. If your `bash` is in, for example, `/usr/bin`, you could just open a root shell and run:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/bash /bin/bash
```

As long as you own the system, or you clear this with the local sysadmin, there should be no problem.

Comment: As a dirty workaround, I believe `ln -s sh /bin/bash` works OK on NixOS.  There's probably a nicer way of setting that up in `configuration.nix`, but I'd say it will still remain a dirty workaround.

Comment: @VladimírČunát why would you do that? sh is not bash, so why would you try to treat it as bash? The OP already knows how to get an sh shell, the question is about getting bash instead. Anyway, doing it this way will not work if you try to run a non portable bash script.

Comment: On (my) NixOS `/bin/sh` seems to be bash.  The binary knows in which mode to run by inspecting `argv[0]`.  Just try setting this up and running `/bin/bash --version`.